# Weird conditional format

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

Throughout my endless journey around the vast and dangerous planes of this beautiful thing also known as `The Internet` I came across a mysterious, old, white-bearded wizard whose name shall not be mentioned. Despite being very powerful death quickly took him away.

Moments before he took his last breath he passed me a scroll and while fainting away whispered

*`Take this and spread the knowledge`*

Quickly after his death his body transformed into energy, pure energy which spread around the universe.

The scroll contained this bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    while(2 <= x <= 5)
        std::cout << x++;
}
```

The mystery remains to this day:

**How is the condition evaluated?**

Comment: Given he was that old, he probably learnt to write in CPL or BCPL, where that conditional behaves as the mathematical statement

Comment: To the close-voters: How is this not a "real question"? -- "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." -- Which of this is true? // +1 for creativity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the composer of this scroll wanted to express a condition we call *chained operator notation*, well known from mathematics (maybe the wizard was a mathematician?):

```
Let x ∈ ℜ, 2 ≤ x ≤ 5. Then ...
```

Normally, this isn't possible in C++, C, Java and a lot of other languages with similar expression evaluation logic. There are libraries which enable such a feature, but on the other hand introduce verbosity because you have to wrap one of the arguments first. Also, it isn't very readable for a programmer.

If you write the expression in such languages as the wizard did on this scroll, it will be evaluated *from left to right*:

```
while ( (2 <= x) <= 5 )
    ...
```

which is always `true`, since `2 <= x` is either `true` or `false` and implicitly cast to an integer value of `1` or `0`, respectively, which is always less or equal `5`.

To express the condition as the mathematician wanted it to be, you have to use the syntax

```
while ( (2 <= x) && (x <= 5) )
    ...
```

or use a utility function to express exactly this:

```
template<class T>
bool between(const T& arg, const T& min, const T& max) {
    return !(arg < min) && !(max < arg);
}


while ( between(x, 2, 5) )
    ...
```

Note how I wrote the condition in `between`: It only requires an implementation of `operator<(T, T)`, easing the implementation of custom types.

Answer (score 13):

Always to true, because `2<=x` either evaluates to `1` or `0`, both of which are `<=5`.

So that's effectively an infinite loop:

```
while( (2 <= x) <= 5)
    std::cout<<x++;
```